# Define condition with Parent and Children classes after filter is applied

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

In Angular 8 I have an Observable:

```
let parents: Observable<Parent[]>;
```

Where `Parent` and `Child` classes are:

```
class Parent {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children: Child[];
}

class Child {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I need to find the `Child`, across all parents' children, which `id` value is 1.

Then I need to define a condition with that `Child` and its `Parent` ... I tried:

```
  parents.pipe(
    map(parents => parents.map(parent => parent.children)),
    map(children => children.find(child => child.id == 1))
    map(child => Test Condition with resulting Child and its Parent
```

The first problem I encountered is that `children` in `map(children =>` is of type `Child[][]` and not `Child[]` so the expression `child.id` fails as child is `Child[]`.

And in the last map I need to have the `Child` but also its `Parent` so I can create the condition and return an `Observable<boolean>`

How can I do this? Can't be done with map?

Comment: Replace your three map() by a single one, which calls a function returning what you want.

Comment: Also, `children` is plural. The singular of `children` is `child`.

Comment: `map(parents => parents.map(parent => parent.childrens))` returns an array of arrays. Concat your results and look for a specific child.

Comment: There is a simple example with flat: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flat()`. You just need to do the same trick. Or concat is able to do the same but it's a long construction: `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [[1, 2], [3, 4]])`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
parents.pipe(
    map(parents => parents.map(parent => parent.children).flat()),
    map(children => children.find(child => child.id == 1))
    map(child => Test Condition with resulting Child and its Parent
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: You code gives me the error "Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'Child[][]'"

Comment: first parents should be called like parentsStream because it's an observable, then you have an array of parents inside the first map.

Comment: Do you use IE or Edge?

Comment: No ... I am using Safari. But the error I am getting is in my JS editor.

Comment: I was able to use flat by adding ES2019 to my project definition. But still with your code I am not sure how to define a condition using child and its parent in the last map as child seems to be of type Child.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use flatMap (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap).
With flatMap, you will kind of join all children-lists to one long list that you can process in the next steps.

I think this should work:

```
const childrenWithId1: Children[] = parents.pipe(
    flatMap(parents => parents),
    flatMap(parent => parent.children),
    filter(child => child.id == 1))
```

Comment: I tried that before but inside `flatMap` parent is of type Parent[] so parent does not have a property children.

Comment: Then flat map parents first... flatMap(parents => parents)

Comment: I updated the code snipped in the original response

Comment: That solves part of the question ... I know there will be only one child with id 1. And then I need to create a condition with that child and its parent ... So getting a Children[] does not me allow to do that. And I need to return an Observable of Boolean wich is the result of that condition